# what does .src and .alt do in the example?

Tags: javascript

I'm currently learning Javascript. I have gotten to the point of `src` and `alt`. I was given this example but I don't understand what is the point of it in this example. Can someone explain, please? (lines 4 and 5). And why is the function Change() executed again at the end ?(full code)

```
function Change() {  
  var first = document.getElementById('traffic');
  var obj = list[next];
  first.src = obj.src;
  first.alt = obj.src;
  timer = setTimeout(Change, obj.interval);
  nextlight = nextlight + 1;
  if (nextlight == list.length)
    nextlight = 0;
}
```

Full code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<body>

<h1>JavaScript Code</h1>
<p>Traffic Light</p>

<img id="traffic" src="only red1.jpg">
<button type="button" onclick="Change()">Change Light</button>

<script>
var list = [{
  src: "only red1.jpg",
  interval: 10000
}, {
  src: "red-yellow 2.jpg",
  interval: 5000
}, {
  src: "green3.jpg",
  interval: 3000
}, {
  src: "yellowonly4.jpg",
  interval: 1000
}];

var next = 0;
var timer;

function Change() {  
  var first = document.getElementById('traffic');
  var obj = list[next];
  first.src = obj.src;
  first.alt = obj.src;
  timer = setTimeout(Change, obj.interval);
  next = next + 1;
  if (next == list.length)
    next = 0;
}

Change();
</script>

</body> 
</html>
```

All help appreciated, I'm just trying to learn.

Comment: Looks like a traffic light.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`obj` contains the `<img>` element, so assigning to `obj.src` and `obj.alt` changes URL that the image displays. If you do

```
obj.src = "green3.jpg";
```

the image will show a green light.

The function is executed at the end so that it will do the first light change, and then start the timer that changes it again after a few seconds.

Comment: yes, I understand, thank you. I deleted the 5th line with .alt and the code works fine but when I delete the src line it doesn't. Does that mean that the src line displays variable obj which is my array list? How does running a function again, at the end work in javascript?

Comment: Do you understand what the `src` and `alt` attributes do in HTML? This just changes them, so it changes the image that's displayed.

Comment: I don't understand your second question. Running a function just executes the code in the function. The way your script works is that the light changes color automatically, and it also changes it when you click on the button. It calls the function at the end to start the automatic timer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stop the iteration once all lights were shown, you need to clear the timeout

```
timer = setTimeout(Change, obj.interval);
nextlight = nextlight + 1;
if (nextlight == list.length)
    clearTimeout(timer);
}
```

For the other question on src and alt

src: Sets the image's source - the path where the image is found

alt: Sets the alternative text, in case no image was found or the browser couldn't show it for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

The src is short for source. In this case it is a object property of the object stored in 'list' and points to images. The Change function iterates over the var list, and uses the different image sources from the objects in list, i.e. it makes sure the traffic light is red, yellow and green. The change function is only executed at the end, it is only declared earlier.

Answer (score 0):

.src gives you the path/source of image & .alt gives the alternate text (if image not found, it shows alternate text on this space)